# firemonkey android not running in Russia

Tags: android, locale, firemonkey

I have compiled a firemonkey android mobile app.
The app connects to a server in Europe. The App expected keyboard entry language is English - regardless of locale and location. The connection is DATASNAP on ports ranging from 220 to 239 inclusive for server connections.

When running in all countries  aside from Russia, the app connects and runs fine. When running in Russia, the App simply closes upon opening.

We set-up a server in Russia to verify this would overrule any potential BAN/blockage related to Russia-related measures.  The App still behaves same way. so this rules out anything that has to do with embargo or a communication blockage.

In addition, the App was tested on 3 different phones in Russia, all yielding the same failed results. All 3 phones had English available for the keyboard.

Do the ports 220-239 need to be somehow registered/approved somehow with carriers/ISP's or use different ports ?

The only other direction that comes to mind is the carriers/operators which may have a requirement or specific settings (maybe compiler) that must set.

Is there something specific to Android for Russia that needs to be addressed, a locale, some other settings?

Any code or perhaps settings solution would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can then obtain debug logs from affected phones and analyze them. If you can't then I think submitting a report to [Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com) is your best bet here.

Answer (score 1):

is seems that in Russia its possible to "connect" to simulated carrier networks (UK/China) and it seems to work. It would be interesting if others experienced this solution as  the only viable one for Russian carriers